# Oracle Select Statement in IF condition

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to use the select statement in IF condition?

For example:

```
IF ( SELECT TotalPrice FROM ORDER WHERE ORDERID = '123' ) > 0 THEN

do something

ELSE 

do something

END IF;
```

THe one way I found is to first assign the value to some variable and use the variable in IF condition like:

```
SELECT TotalPrice into Variable FROM ORDER WHERE ORDERID = '123' ;
IF variable > 0 Then
....
END IF
```

Is there a way to do it without using the variable?

Comment: Nope, use the variable, Oracle does not support SQL in that context without an INTO. With a properly named variable your code will be more legible anyway.

Answer (score 2):

as @Wolf already stated it is **not possible**.